# The perception of mathematics

Tags: soft-question, examples-counterexamples, education

In my work I wrote the following sentence.

> "...there is a negative perception of mathematics and mathematicians, both within and outside of academia."

Err. Right. So, I believe that this is true, and I suppose most people here do (although perhaps the "within...academia" bit is *maybe* contentious). However, I have been searching for some time now and am struggling to back either point up with a good, solid source or example (I *did* find an article which said "It is widely maintained in the literature that negative images and myths of mathematics are widespread among the public", but then this wasn't backed up by a reference!). This intrigues me. I certainly feel that this is true. For example, if someone asks me "What do you do?" and I reply "I am a mathematician!" the most common response is "Oh. Right. Err...I need the loo, be right back!"...but...*they never return*...

So, I have two questions:

- Can you please give me a good, solid *and recent* source or example which backs up my point that there is a negative perception of mathematics and mathematicians among the general public?
- Can you please give me a good, solid *and recent* source or example which backs up my point that there is a negative perception of mathematics and mathematicians within academia?

I emphasise the *and recent* because perceptions change with time. I am not interested in "The perception of mathematics among elementary school teachers" in 1984 (or even in 2000), but I *am* interested in this in 2010.

Now, I would be grateful if answers didn't simply give examples of "ordinary people" or English professors who had a penchant for mathematics. I know these people exist. Rather, I want to know what the general feeling amongst these two groups are. So general stuff, not specifics.

Finally, there is also the possible discussion of "If you cannot answer the second question, is this because there is *not* a negative perception of mathematics and mathematicians within all areas academia (specifically, the science-ey parts)?". This *does* interest me, but it isn't really suitable for MSE. So if you have an opinion on this matter, I would be grateful if you kept it to the comments. Or you could give a good, solid backed-up-with-recent-sources answer. But it had better be good!

Comment: One big misconception I think people have is that people think mathematicians are highly logical people and in my opinion, that's not at all true.

Comment: To make it short: I don't believe that your sentence is true (both parts).

Comment: @user1729I laughed at the *counterexample* tag. It's adequate, though.

Comment: @GitGud It was the best I could find!

Comment: I do not know if it can be considered as a negative perception, but once a friend of mine asked me "why are you studying math? Isn't all already known?". He was serious and deeply worried about my time management.

Comment: I strongly agree with Git Gud's top comment: mathematicians are supposed to be coherent with math logic while studying math. Outside that world they are just like everybody else (so is "everybody else" negatively perceived? :) ). ps: in Jurassic Park the black suited math guy gets the chick...(and a T-Rex)

Comment: @O.L. I want to say "would you care to elaborate?" but I really want this question to deal with scientific "fact" (erm, note the quote marks! as in, studies or polls or something) so, in a certain sense, I am not after belief. However, I am sure you have a reason for this belief. Is it possible to write down the reason for your belief without using opinion and narrow examples?  (I wrote this reply with a grimace on my face - I would love to hear your opinion, but want to deal with fact. Can you oblige?)

Comment: @Avitus But "getting the girl" that is a negative perception! It was only in the film because it was breaking the stereotype!

Comment: For the second question, I recall a quote from a famous mathematician. Unfortunately, I forgot his name and the exact wording, but it was something in the lines of: "Every mathematician thinks they are better than the other mathematicians, but they are smart enough not to express this opinion." I myself have the more extreme opinion that mathematicians in fact hate each other.

Comment: @user1729 If you want "facts", you will have to first define "negative perception". Negative with respect to what/whom inside and outside academia? world-wide or country specific? I am pretty sure when you will formulate yourself an answerable question, the answer to it will be obvious.

Comment: @user1729 I got it the other way round: the math guy is able to explain math in a fancy and charming way seducing the lady in 0.161803398 nanoseconds. Your "I certainly feel that this is true" is such a strong statement! I do not think you need any reference after that ;)

Comment: @LordSoth Wait, wait, wait! The question was about perception in the whole academia. Perceptions of mathematicians by mathematicians is yet another delicate story.

Comment: @O.L. OK, OK, OK! In any case, $\mathtt{Math}\subset\mathtt{Acad}$.

Comment: Would those voting to close please help me to improve my question by -erm- telling me why they are voting to close?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by having a *negative perception of mathematics*. If it means having had unpleasant experiences with mathematics, not understanding it, etc., then at least a quarter of the statement is probably true: there is a widespread negative perception of mathematics outside academia. If it means believing that mathematics is useless, not worth studying, etc., then I’m not at all sure that it’s true. And I’m not at all sure that there is a widespread negative perception of mathematicians. Widespread lack of understanding, yes; negative perception, not at all clear.

Answer (score 9):

What follows doesn't fit your definition of "recent", but I think you'll find this book review *very interesting* and funny and on-target for what you're asking about:

Conrad Plaut, [Review of Michale K. Smith's 1994 book](http://www.ams.org/notices/199507/plaut.pdf) [**Humble Pi**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0879758775), **Notices of the American Mathematical Society** 42 #7 (July 1995), 772-773.

Comment: Oooooh - yes, sounds like a lovely read! Erm, not sure I could buy it whilst keeping my conscience in-tact though.